Android web-view reload is not reloading on reload click
 private fun reloadWebViewOnClick(){
        //webview reload
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
            launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                binding?.webview?.reload()
            }
        }
    }

I have tried log but controle never enter at reload scope. I am unable find what I am missing.

Please change launchWhenResumed to launch because launch will work only when the fragment resumes.
private fun reloadWebViewOnClick(){
    //webview reload
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            binding?.webview?.reload()
        }
    }
}


I have tried this. Thank you so much it is working now. You have saved my day.
